# Nginx - proxy_pass on error

Tags: nginx

I was attempting to proxy_pass for error_page with proxy_intercept_errors enabled, but getting an error.

I assume that’s because error_page only allows a static HTML page? Is the any way around this?

Comment: You can do something like this `error_page 403 = @denied;` and then handle the request in a location as you would any other location

Comment: There's an example on [the manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page).

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to Drifter104 and Richard Smith

> If there is no need to change URI and method during internal redirection it is possible to pass error processing into a named location:

```
location / {
    error_page 404 = @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```